# How to convert .rpm file into .deb file in Fedora 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I am using 64 bit fedora10 linux. I have created rpm file for my software. It works fine. But my software doesnot works good or ubuntu and debian linux because they want .deb file.

How to convert my .rpm file into .deb file?

Comment: This might not "belong" on superuser; but it will definately get an answer there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `debootstrap` package to create Debian/Ubuntu chroot and build .deb package inside it. It would be better then just converting from existing RPM to DEB.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a (legal) alien: http://packages.debian.org/lenny/alien

Comment: Hu carl, Whether I have to use ubuntuu linux or I can do in fedora linux.

Comment: Well, alien is a debian (= Ubuntu) application so it's sure to run most easily there. But it also runs on Fedora: <http://www.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/alien/>